# Combinatorics problem involving counting the number of certain substrings

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

I'm not sure if this question is suited for MO, but it does seem quite challenging to me, and is required for a research problem in chemistry I'm working on. I did try getting help from elsewhere ([Cross-post on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126285/how-to-count-the-number-of-substrings-in-this-combinatorics-problem)), but no luck so far. So I apologize if this question is unwelcome here.

Let's say I'm making a string of $A$s and $B$s, where the number of $A$s and $B$s are $a$ and $b$ respectively. A total of $a+b \choose a$ such strings are possible. Now, I wish to know the total number of '$ABA$' and '$BAB$' substrings that occur in all such strings. How do I count this?

Comment: How would you handle the case of overlaps?  For example, would the string $ABAB$ give a count of two?

Comment: Any occurrence of either of those substrings would add to the count. So yes, $ABAB$ would give a count of two.

Comment: If ever you edit your question again, include the [tag:combinatorics-on-words] tag; that might lead to more attention.  (But perhaps do it a few hours or days from now.)

Comment: I suppose that *substring* in your question means factor and not subsequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of sequences with ABA or BAB at one specific place is
$$\binom{a+b-3}{a-2}+\binom{a+b-3}{a-1}=\binom{a+b-2}{a-1}.$$
Hence the total number of ABA and BAB is
$$(a+b-2)\binom{a+b-2}{a-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) But couldn't there be strings amongst the $a+b \choose a$ strings, in which the $ABA$ or $BAB$ substrings occur more than once? This calculation doesn't take them into account, does it?

Comment: Of course there exist strings with more than one substring ABA and BAB and the calculation does take this into account.

Comment: User35593's argument is basically equivalent to the "linearity of expectation". What you want to do is for each string, count # positions with ABA or BAB; and then add up over strings. What this does instead is for each position it asks how many strings have an ABA or BAB in that position; and then adds this up. It's equivalent to having a grid of numbers and then adding the rows first before adding the columns; or vice versa.

Comment: Absolutely the correct answer to the question as asked. For more detailed statistics, the Goulden-Jackson cluster method (which is hard to explain in a comment - but the phrase is a good start for google) could be used in this, and many similar contexts.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thank you! :)

Comment: @MichaelAlbert: Thank you for the reference, I shall look it up.